# Programmatically draw image in Anylogic

Tags: image, drawable, anylogic

Is there any way to programmatically draw images in Anylogic? Only method I found so far is to add Image element to project, specify its image from filesystem and then getting it from cache at runtime (for example `getPresentation().getPanel().getImageCache().getCachedImage( this, "/wandering_elephants/", "Altitudes.PNG", 500, 500 );`) and draw to it.

But this seems to be paint in the ass in case you need to create variable sized images. I have been looking for some Drawable element in palette, but it seems this basic functionality is missing.

Comment: not really sure what you are aiming at? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to dynamically draw some background "map" for agents to show information about world. For instance, in Wandering elephants example in Anylogic they show height map of terrain generated dynamically. To do this, author uses Image element from pallete with some empty PNG file. Then he loads this image from cache as mentioned in my question and draws to its graphics. So obviously there is need for some generic drawable element. Need to fake some empty image and then getting it from cache just to gain ability to draw seems like a terrible overkill and lack of needed feature.

Comment: ok, sorry but I am still not quite clear. Are there several background images you want to show depending on some model conditions? Because the Image object can hold as many images as you want (preloaded during design time in the properties). You can then switch which one should be visible accessing them by index. Did you try that?

Comment: If you have Anylogic by hand just look at the Wandering elephants example model, more precisely at its map (vegetation, sand, water) rendering process at runtime. I unfortunately don´t know how to better describe what I want - just some simple element you could insert from pallete which would provide programmatic drawing ability without need to load some fake blank image from cache - like it is done in mentioned example.

Comment: had a look, not even sure why they use the image at all. For that kind of background, you could just use replicated rectangles that you color dynamically. Would be easier on performance as well.

Comment: Interesting, because I have also used replicated rectangles as shown in Harvest Simulator example. Is there any option to add more rectangles dynamically during simulation runtime? For example, I need to draw maze of variable dimensions from blocks of certain size. Therefore if user chooses to change maze dimension during simulation I would need to add more rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replicated rectangles. To change the number of replications, use a variable of type int named numberOfReplications. Stick that into the "Replication" property of your rectangle and you can change that variable dynamically.

cheers

Comment: But what about situations when you need to add more rectangles based on simulation progress or user input during simulation? I believe you cannot add more rectangles programatically after simulation starts.

Comment: you can always create any object programmatically as it is all  just Java. For a rectangle, check http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/javadoc/com/anylogic/engine/presentation/ShapeRectangle.html

Comment: Sure but you have to somehow add it to Main agent class so it will be drawn and handled by it. I have inspected generated Java code without any indication this can be done at runtime using provided API.

Comment: It is possible for sure. You need to add it to the presentation manually, that is correct. Worth checking AL support and documentation for that (or do by trial and error), I never remember this, sorry :-(